# How to use a tuple's 6 values as 6 keys in a dictionary, and print the dictionary's corresponding values?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, key

I hope to print `flist`(a dictionary)'s corresponding values(6 values in total) based on the all keys(6 keys in total) in a tuple, but how?

The 6 keys in the dictionary is all the tuple's values(6 in total). The dictionary has 100+ key, value pairs

```py
s = pd.Series(files['file_name'] + "." + files['file_type'])

for key, value in s.items():
    print(f" value : {value}")

for value in s:
    if value in flist.keys():
        print(flist.values())
```

I know the last line is not correct, I should print `flist`'s corresponding values(6 values in total) based on the all keys(6 keys in total) in the tuple, but how?

Comment: Can you provide sample data & what you hope to produce from it?

Comment: Correct indentation in Python code is crucial. [Edit] your question and fix it.

Comment: Are you looking for [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=operator%20itemgetter#operator.itemgetter)? `itemgetter(a, b, c)(d) == (d[a], d[b], d[c])`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question fully, but you can use [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=operator%20itemgetter#operator.itemgetter) as suggested in one of the comments, or [if you don't want to depend on the `operator` module] something like

```py
def get_tuple_of_values(dict_w100plus_kvp:dict, keysRef, defaultVal=None):
    return tuple(dict_w100plus_kvp.get(k,defaultVal) for k in keysRef)
```

will return a tuple of the same length as `keysRef`, which can be be a tuple or dictionary or list [or any iterable really, as long as it only contains hashable values that might be keys in `dict_w100plus_kv`].

Comment: There's no drawback to depending on the `operator` module; it's part of the standard library, so if it's not available, something is very, very wrong.

Comment: @chepner my habit is to import as few modules as possible - it's mostly a matter of personal preference...but also, in this case I don't see much advantage to it either? this is pretty much what it does anyway [for multiple keys] except mine is more forgiving as it uses `.get`

Comment: Importing as few modules as possible means you are reinventing the wheel a lot.

Comment: True, but I prefer not to buy a car when all I want is a wheel